# Primefaces 6.0 and 6.1 contextMenu and node type issue

Tags: primefaces, tree, contextmenu

I don't know why but the context menu for a specific type of node doesn't work with the last version of primefaces 6.0 et 6.1 (I need the 6.1 to use the new TextEditor component), but It works fine with the 5.3 version.
With 6.x only the last context menu appears the other ones are just ignored.

Any idea ?

Comment: Please read [ask], specifically the [mcve] part

Comment: like said in the comment before read how to ask (add what you tried to see if there is something wrong )